# Detect current underlying theme in Vaadin 7 app

Tags: themes, vaadin, vaadin7

How to detect the current underlying theme in use in a [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) 7 app?

Vaadin 7 apps created by using the [current Maven archetypes](https://vaadin.com/maven) or the IDE plugins ([NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50531/vaadin-plug-in-for-netbeans), [Eclipse](http://vaadin.com/eclipse)) have a custom theme named `mytheme` installed by default. In the current Vaadin 7.5.3, this custom theme extends the new [Valo theme](https://vaadin.com/valo). In the old days it extended the [Reindeer theme](http://demo.vaadin.com/ReindeerTheme).

When I call [`UI::getTheme`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html) the string `mytheme` returns, the name of that custom theme.

So how do I get the current *underlying* theme’s name? I want the string defined by constants such as [`ValoTheme.THEME_NAME`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/themes/ValoTheme.html#THEME_NAME) or [`Reindeer.THEME_NAME`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/themes/Reindeer.html#THEME_NAME)?

One use for this is knowing which style name string ([`ValoTheme.BUTTON_PRIMARY`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/themes/ValoTheme.html#BUTTON_PRIMARY), [`Reindeer.BUTTON_DEFAULT`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/themes/Reindeer.html#BUTTON_DEFAULT), etc.) to add when changing the look of a button to be a default button (a.k.a. primary button) as seen [here in the Book Of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.shortcuts.html#advanced.shortcuts.defaultbutton).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but I annotate my UI class with `@Theme(ValoTheme.THEME_NAME)`. Then in any place I could call `getCurrent().getTheme()` or `UI.getCurrent().getTheme()` and as result I obtain "valo" string. This is what you want to achieve?

Comment: @jsosnowski If you want to add any CSS tweaks at all, you must create a custom theme. To use that custom theme, you must annotate with `@Theme ( "mytheme" )` rather than `@Theme(ValoTheme.THEME_NAME)`. Indeed, this is already done for you in an automatically-configured project when using the current Maven archetypes or IDE plugin for Vaadin. Perhaps my Question is really about detecting the *underlying* theme.

Comment: I don't think there's a safe way to deduce it since the _inheritance_ happens in the CSS files. A simple solution would be to define a mapping between the theme name and the style names to be applied, given that you'll be the one to create the themes as well, so you should know who extends/inherits what.  Nonetheless, do you have a particular scenario in mind where you would need both reindeer and valo?

Comment: @Morfic I was writing a generic class to extend `Button` to be a default button. so it could be running in different apps under any of the themes. I have realized a **workaround**: *Add each style name from **all** the themes.* CSS ignores any undefined style name, so no harm done by the extraneous ones. Therefore, no need to detect which theme is active.